# Overload Templated Function for All String Types

Tags: c++, template-specialization, overloading

I have the following template:

```
template<class T>
void fn(T t){ }
```

and I'd like to override its behavior for anything that can be converted to `std::string`.

Both specifying an explicit template specialization and a non-template function overload with the parameter as an `std::string` only work for calls that pass in an `std::string` and not other functions, since it seems to be matching them to the template before attempting argument conversion.

Is there a way to achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this case help you in C++11

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value, void>::type
fn(T t)
{
   std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value, void>::type
fn(T t) 
{
   std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   fn("hello");
   fn(std::string("new"));
   fn(1);
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/9qFBVA)

And of course, you can realize it manually, if you have no C++11, or use boost.